# C# struct changed to class caused too many redirects in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, class, struct

I had a VS/C# project with structs containing similar structs.
I converted it to an array of structs, but I had to convert my main struct to class to achieve this.
Now my browser says "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".
Here is my story:

Code before: (simplified example, compiles, works)

```
public struct mainStruct
{
  public struDoor rDoor1;
  public struDoor rDoor2;
}
```

Compiles, but rDoors needs to be allocated runtime:

```
public struct mainStruct
{
  public struDoor[] rDoors;
}
```

Code after: (does not compile)

```
public struct mainStruct
{
  public struDoor rDoors[2];
}
```

Code after: (does not compile)

```
public struct mainStruct
{
  public struDoor[] rDoors = new struDoor[2];
}
```

Google told me convert my struct to class.

Now it compiles, but causes "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in browser:

```
public class mainStruct
{
  public struDoor[] rDoors = new struDoor[2];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Maybe the problem is somewhere else?
Debug seems to be not working, becouse it happens before the Page_Load().
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show the code as it relates to your page that issues a redirect.  You show a structure, but not how it is used, so it's hard to say why it may be resulting in redirect.  Also, try tracing to see where it is redirecting to so you have some context to what may be happening.

Comment: would it be too difficult for you to change your `struct` to a `Class` and perhaps instantiate a `List<Class>`

Comment: Sounds like you're doing a comparison between two instances of `mainStruct` with the same values but a different identity. Since structs have value identity and classes don't, the equality comparison used to compare the values, but now it only compares the references. As for why you can't initialise fields in a struct - there's no way to provide your own default constructor in a struct, because the default constructor is really "take pre-zeroed memory" and that's it - it doesn't really *run*, it's just the way an empty structure *is*.

Comment: can we see the "decide whether to redirect" code?

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is chrome telling you the page has tried to reload too many times.  I think your issue is unrelated to the code shown.

Comment: I'm guessing someone is still accessing rDoor1 and rDoor2 causing an error and the error handler is redirecting to the same page.

Comment: @PeteG: Maybe my issue is unrelated to the code, but changing the struct to class brings up the issue and I am unable to debug the error. What do you recommend? The source code itself is huge.

Comment: Maybe is there any better way to make a static array of structs inside of a struct?